# cmake Failed to checkout tag: 'master'

Tags: cmake

Im trying to build an open source project that uses external project.

I forked the external project and I replaced these lines

`GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenSfM/`

`GIT_TAG           264`

with

`GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/myname/OpenSfM/`

When i try to build, i get error below;

```
fatal: invalid reference: master
CMake Error at /code/SuperBuild/build/opensfm/tmp/opensfm-gitclone.cmake:40 (message):
   Failed to checkout tag: 'master'

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opensfm.dir/build.make:110: opensfm/stamp/opensfm-download] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:350: CMakeFiles/opensfm.dir/all] Error 2
```

OpenSfM repo uses main tag for master branch.

What happens if cmake fails to checkout nonexistent tag ? Does compilation continue with main branch ?

Comment: "What happens if cmake fails to checkout nonexistent tag?" - CMake just calls `git` with appropriate arguments. If that call fails, CMake fails too. There is no such thing in CMake like "try to clone this or try to clone that".

Comment: allright, i know i could set it to main. but it is kind of time/energy wasting. most of new repos uses main tag. but default GIT_TAG is set to master in CMake.

[Git 2.28.0, released in July 2020, introduced the init.defaultBranch configuration option, which allows Git users to define and configure a default branch name other than master.](https://sfconservancy.org/news/2020/jun/23/gitbranchname/)